# C# windows server 2008 r2 win32exception

Tags: iis-7.5, windows-server-2008-r2, c#-2.0

We have a .net 2.0 exe that we are running on windows server 2008 r2. It gets stucks and stops with below info on Event log.

The same used to run correctly on windows server 2003. there are no code changes or rebuilds done in the migration to windows server 2008 r2.

We have tried putting lots of logs in exception in our code, but not sure from which line of code this error popups, but our normal logs do popup in the eventvwr, so doesnt look like permission issue on event viewer.

Any help or pointers on  this would be helpful.

```
1) Exception Information
*********************************************
Exception Type: System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception
NativeErrorCode: 87
ErrorCode: -2147467259
Message: The parameter is incorrect
Data: System.Collections.ListDictionaryInternal
TargetSite: Void InternalWriteEvent(UInt32, UInt16, System.Diagnostics.EventLogEntryType, System.String[], Byte[], System.String)
HelpLink: NULL
Source: System
```

```
2) StackTrace Information
*********************************************
   at System.Diagnostics.EventLog.InternalWriteEvent(UInt32 eventID, UInt16 category, EventLogEntryType type, String[] strings, Byte[] rawData, String currentMachineName)
   at System.Diagnostics.EventLog.WriteEntry(String message, EventLogEntryType type, Int32 eventID, Int16 category, Byte[] rawData)
   at System.Diagnostics.EventLog.WriteEntry(String source, String message, EventLogEntryType type, Int32 eventID, Int16 category, Byte[] rawData)
   at System.Diagnostics.EventLog.WriteEntry(String source, String message, EventLogEntryType type, Int32 eventID, Int16 category)
   at DefaultPublisher.WriteToLog(String entry, EventLogEntryType type)
   at DefaultPublisher.Publish(Exception exception, NameValueCollection additionalInfo, NameValueCollection configSettings)
   at ExceptionManager.Publish(Exception exception, NameValueCollection additionalInfo)
```

Comment: Hello all, any inputs ?

Comment: Hello anyone, please provide any feedback or pointers for this issue

Answer (score 0):

The message passed to `WriteEntry()` is too long. It's length must be less than 32706 characters

Comment: It also may not contain certain characters such as %, or they need to be escaped